# How to redeem coupon code which i created in django?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, postman

I created Coupon code in django rest framework and now i like to redeem it using python script or any frontend method like html, javascript,Postman, i don't have way, path or logic which can guide me on how to do it.

Here is my models.py file :

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator, MaxValueValidator


class Coupon(models.Model):
    code = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    valid_from = models.DateTimeField()
    valid_to = models.DateTimeField()
    discount = models.IntegerField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    active = models.BooleanField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code
```

here is my serializers.py file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Coupon


class CouponSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Coupon
        fields = '__all__'
```

here is my views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Coupon
from .serializers import CouponSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets


class CouponViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Coupon.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CouponSerializer
```

**Please do help**

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to have an end user attempt to use a code, and you would like django to check validity of the code & process a response?

Comment: @PacketLoss I like to redeem code using postman, python script, javascript, html anything and for that i need to make changes in views.py file but i don't know what exactly i need to do i am new in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new action in your viewset where you can check the validity of the code and provide an appropriate response.

```
    class CouponViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Coupon.objects.all()
        serializer_class = CouponSerializer
    
        @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
        def redeem(self, request, pk=None):
            obj = self.get_object()
            // do all the checks here.
            return Response(// return data what needed)
```

You can change the method of this custom method according to your need if you want to send additional data.
Also note that if you are using this coupon to create an order, do send this coupon in the final request where you can verify the discount again.

You can map the different serializer for each action in your viewset.

```
# mapping serializer into the action
    serializer_classes = {
        'list': PatientDischargeListSerializer,
        'retrieve': PatientDischargeReadSerializer,
        'create': PatientDischargeSerializer,
        'update': PatientDischargeSerializer,
        'partial_update': PatientDischargeSerializer,
        'redeem': CustomSerializer,
    }
    default_serializer_class = PatientDischargeSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self):
        return self.serializer_classes.get(self.action, self.default_serializer_class)

    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def redeem(self, request, pk=None):
        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        obj = self.get_object()
        serializer = serializer_class(instance=obj, data=request.data)
        // do all the checks here.
        return Response(// return data what needed)
```

Comment: Hi , can you elaborate little more please if possible. I am new in django so

Comment: Yes, I can, which part you need me to elaborate on?

Comment: ViewSet, i mean how to create

Comment: Are you unsing router ?

Comment: yes i am, i want to ask is i created models.py i created serializers.py file but now i want to create views.py or viewSet which can redeem or validate the coupon but i am not exactly getting how should i create it.

Comment: Hi when you said do all the checks here which checks you exactly meant?